# xcode 4.5, IOS 6.0, Jenkins 1.476, OSX 10.7.5, Cordova / Phone Gap, Will not build under Jenkins

Tags: xcode, build, jenkins, ios6

Getting the following error under Jenkins.  Hand builds on the same machine using Xcode and / or other command line build working fine.  I assume this has something to do with the IOS 6.0 / Xcode upgrade since it was working fine before this.  Top level project is not compiling with the Architecture set for armv7 and Valid Architecture armv7.  This builds and runs fine for the V6.0 simulator and devices when done on the same machine by hand with Xcode.

```
 CompileC build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/Objects-  normal/armv7/MyAppAgent_vers.o build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/DerivedSources/MyAppAgent_vers.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DNDEBUG=1, -DCORDOVA_FRAMEWORK=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -iquote /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/MyAppAgent-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/MyAppAgent-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/MyAppAgent-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/MyAppAgent-project-headers.hmap -iquote../../../Include -iquote../../../Include/logging -iquote../../../Include/messaging -iquote../../../Include/networking -iquote../../../Include/platform -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Builds/MyAppAgent/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Builds/MyAppAgent -F/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/../../../../SDK -F/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/../../../../SDK -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyAppAgent_vers.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyAppAgent_vers.dia -c /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/DerivedSources/MyAppAgent_vers.c -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyAppAgent/workspace/Dev/Projects/MyApp/MyAppAgent/build/MyAppAgent.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyAppAgent.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyAppAgent_vers.o

clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=5.0'

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version of Xcode, the default setting of i386 Architectures includes the new iphone 5 armv7s.  Some of the items we were linking in, did not include armv7s and we were bugging out.  Needed to change the Workspace (in our case) not to be the default arch, but to specify armv7 only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building with the simulator SDK, make sure the CPU architecture is set to i386.

Comment: What actually worked for me is that I have set Valid Architectures exactly to i386. I have done that in separate target created solely for building with xcodebuild. This worked for older version of Xcode and for the one specified above. Although both were giving different errors. I have notice that having Valid Architectures set to "armv7 i386" caused that each file was build 2 times for each architecture.